# Open File Dialog not working in c#!

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Music|*.mp3";
        if(ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(ofd.FileName);
            sp.Play();
        }
    }
```

I tried the given code but its not showing up.Instead of that program freezes.
And off course there is already [STATHREAD] in main method.Please help!

Comment: PLeaser use the debugger, set breakpoints. Where exactly _freezes_ your program? What are the variables values (expected vs. actual)? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the SoundPlayer's Play() method is a blocking call and so as you're running this on your UI thread it's preventing the UI from doing anything until it has finished playing.

Try launching the player as a separate thread and see if that causes your program not to freeze.

Comment: `SoundPlayer.Play()` is the asynchronous call. The class has a `PlaySync()` method that is synchronous. So your theory is incorrect. The real problem here is that the OP didn't bother to provide a useful question that could be answered. Best to not try to answer such questions.